Should the [ps1] tag be used, and if not, should it be removed?
Tag ps1 has no guidance, with only 44 questions using it, however the main problem is .ps1 is a PowerShell profile and script extension, but is being used both for PowerShell and other shells that really aren't relevant to it:

While BSD/Linux shells do use the PS1 variable within their shell RC files, it's so widely attributed with PowerShell even syntax highlighter highlight.js uses ps1 for PowerShell (which will be a supported code syntax on this site when it's eventually added and that oversight bug fixed)

If the ps1 tag should be used, it would make far more sense for BSD/Linux shell PS1 variable questions to be tagged with their shell and shell config tags, not tag ps1, and for this guidance to be within the tag's guidance.

A quick glance shows a question about an IBM PS1 ._. - I wonder if a clearer tag for the PS usage + retagging everything else makes sense

@JourneymanGeek IBM PS/1 is a single question for 34yr old hardware, and seems unlikely to garnish more than a handful of questions in the coming decades =] (if going that route, it seems like a tag for it would make more sense as ps-1 since that would also apply to PS/1 hardware like legacy keyboard/mice). .ps1 is a widely used file extension on billions of files and billions of machines since every Windows install comes with more than one .ps1 file, and would seem to make more sense to treat it as a file extension like batch-file, sh, etc. (if not ps1, perhaps ps1-file?)

Or possibly bash-ps1 (or appropriate language) and powershell-ps1 . Wierdly not entirely sure what's the convention here

I'd say the PowerShell usage is pretty much useless - the extension doesn't tell anything extra about the question 99.99% of the time, powershell tag is enough, PS1 variable is much more specific and better fit - but don't think bash-ps1 is accurate as it applies to lots of shells.
